# Magento 2 - get amount of items in cart by using knockout.js

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, knockoutjs, header

I am creating a new header. It is supposed to look like this:

[image]

I need to get the number of items in the cart and write it to a certain place in the header, where the minicart is showing. So I added this code to my layout **MY_THEME\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
    <container name="header-container" htmlTag="div" htmlId="header_container" htmlClass="min768 grid">

        <!-- Logo -->
            <container name="hf_header_logo" htmlTag="div" htmlId="hf_header_logo_container"/>

        <!-- Searchbar -->
            <container name="hf_header_search" htmlTag="div" htmlId="hf_header_search_container">
                ...
            </container>

        <!-- User Area -->
            <container name="hf_header_user" htmlTag="div" htmlId="hf_header_user_container">
                ...
            </container>

        <!-- Cart -->
            <container name="hf_header_cart" htmlTag="div" htmlId="hf_header_cart_container">
                <container name="minicart-row" label="Wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="minicart-wrapper" htmlId="old_minicart">
                    <container name="mini-wk" label="Mini-Wk" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="mini-wk">
                        <container name="mini-wk-content" label="Minicart-Main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="mini-wk-content row no-gutters">
                            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar"
                                   name="desktop_minicart_block"
                                   template="Magento_Checkout::cart/header_minicart.phtml">
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="types" xsi:type="array"/>
                                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart</item>
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/content</item>
                                                </item>
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="subtotal.container" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">subtotalContainer</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/subtotal</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                    <item name="extra_info" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">extraInfo</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                    <item name="promotion" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">promotion</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </block>
                        </container>
                    </container>
                </container>
            </container>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

As you can see I already injected the arguments like seen in the original layout file in `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\default.xml`

This is how I try to get the number of items in the cart in **MY_THEME\Magento_Checkout\templates\cart\header_minicart.phtml**:

```
<span class="counter-label" data-bind="html: getCartParam('subtotal')">
<!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
    <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
</span>
```

But it does not render the number.

In the browser console I get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return getCartParam('summary_count') }"
Message: getCartParam is not defined
    at if (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2982), <anonymous>:3:55)
    at ko.computed.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:4381)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate_CallReadThenEndDependencyDetection (knockout.js:2173)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate_CallReadWithDependencyDetection (knockout.js:2140)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:2101)
    at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:1954)
    at init (knockout.js:4380)
    at knockout.js:3358
    at Object.ignore (knockout.js:1470)
    at knockout.js:3357
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

My code works but I had to delete generated files and static content.

I just executed `grunt clean` and now it works